# Changing a dom related element upon event

Tags: javascript

My document has multiple dom elements with class "vatcheckbox" (checkbox) that, when changed/clicked, should disable a dom-related element with "vatfield" class (input field).

I have tried the following :

```
document.querySelector('.vatcheckbox').addEventListener('change', function()
  { this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.vatfield').disabled = this.checked;
    }
    )
```

It does work if there is a single instance of `.vatcheckbox`. But when there is multiple instances of `.vatcheckbox` the changes append to the first `.vatcheckbox` element only.

Comment: Need relevant HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without any library

```
document.querySelectorAll('.vatcheckbox').forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.vatfield').disabled = this.checked;
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the event listener in a JQuery `each`:

```
$('.vatcheckbox').each(function(idx) {
  this.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.vatfield').disabled = this.checked;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution in Jquery works too. 
I realise I had a problem with my label as well: clicking the actual checkbox works as intended but clicking the label triggers change on first dome element .. Will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**HTMLFormElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) and [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interfaces to reference [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Value). Use [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to control the behavior of all checkboxes that have the same `[name]` attribute when a specific checkbox is checked.

In the demo, all checkboxes are wrapped in a form tag. All checkboxes with `[name=ver]` will be disabled when the checkbox with #id of `#vat` is checked and vice versa. Details commented in demo.

```js
// Reference form
const form = document.forms['main'];
// Reference all form controls
const x = form.elements;
// Reference all input[name=ver]
const vers = x.ver;

/** onOff()
//A - Pass Event Object
//B - Iterate through all input[name=ver]...
//C - if the origin of event is checked...
//D - disable each input[name=ver]...
//E - Otherwise enable each input[name=ver]
*/
function onOff(e) { //A
  for (let ver of vers) { //B
    if (e.target.checked) { //C
      ver.disabled = true; //D
    } else {
      ver.disabled = false; //E
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Register input#vat to the change event -- call onOff on change event
x.vat.onchange = onOff;
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <input id='vat' type='checkbox'> VAT
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='anything' type='checkbox'> Anything
  <input name='else' type='checkbox'> Else<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='anything' type='checkbox'> Anything
  <input name='else' type='checkbox'> Else
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='ver' type='checkbox'> verify<br>
  <input name='anything' type='checkbox'> Anything
  <input name='else' type='checkbox'> Else<br>
</form>
```